# Would 10.0 mL of water at 10 °C have the same mass as 10.0 mL of water at 25 °C?

Tags: units

I am reading a book and it gives the following answer:

> No, the density of water changes with
> temperature. 10.0 mL of water at 10 °C would
> have a higher mass than 10.0 mL of water at
> 25 °C because the density is higher at 10 °C.

For me it doesn't make sense. In other part of the book it states "Mass is defined as the amount of matter in an object". How can a change in temperature change the amount of matter of an object? So mass of an object is dependent on temperature?

Comment: Heating up 10 **g** of water does not change its mass, as you say. But that's not what this question is about. This is about two different amounts of water: 10 **mL** of water at 10 °C (let's say in a measuring cylinder), and 10 **mL** of water at 25 *C (in, let's say, a different measuring cylinder). The amount of water in the two measuring cylinders is not the same.

Comment: In fact, heating up 10 mL of water does not change its mass, either. However, it *will* change its volume, such that at 25 °C it is no longer 10 mL. Hence, 10 mL of water at 10 °C is not the same thing as 10 mL of water at 25 °C. Hence my suggestion to think of them as completely different samples. They are not the same object.

Comment: $m_1 = \rho_1V;$ $m_2 = \rho_2V.$ When $\rho_1 > \rho_2,$ $m_1 > m_2.$ What is the problem? And, yes, comparing two *identical* bodies at different temperatures will result in minuscular difference in mass ([hotter one will be a slight bit heavier](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/152873/will-heating-up-an-object-increase-its-mass)), but this is not what your textbook (which, by the way, should be properly referenced) is trying to say.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I understand now!

Comment: Please find a better book. See if you can get hold of Linus Pauling's College Chemistry: An Introductory Textbook of General Chemistry

Comment: @M.Farooq why? Is the sentence too obvious?

Comment: @Alchimista, Apparently the book didn't deliver the concept of density very well.

Answer (score 1):

Changing temperature doesn't change the mass of a fixed amount of a substance. But it does change the density. So a 10mL sample of water at 25 celcius will still contain the same amount of substance at 10 celcius. But it will not longer occupy exactly 10mL, but will be a slightly smaller volume.

Since you specified the conditions as having *fixed* volume, you would need to add a (small) extra amount of water to get 10mL at the lower temperature. So, at fixed volume, there *would* be more water.

Think carefully about *all* the conditions you specify in comparisons and be consistent.